# About the definition of a vector in "Mechanics I" by Akira Harashima. Do I understand this definition?

Tags: vectors, definition, coordinate-systems

I am reading "Mechanics I" (in Japanese) by Akira Harashima.

> A quantity is given by three real numbers $(A_x, A_y, A_z)$ in an orthogonal coordinate system $S$, and for another orthogonal coordinate system $S'$ (assuming the origin of $S$ and the orign of $S'$ are the same), it is given by three real numbers $(A_{x'}, A_{y'}, A_{z'})$.
> If $(A_x, A_y, A_z)$ and $(A_{x'}, A_{y'}, A_{z'})$ satisfy the following relations, then $(A_x, A_y, A_z)$ and $(A_{x'}, A_{y'}, A_{z'})$ represent a single vector $\mathbf{A}$.
> $$
> A_{x'}=l_1A_x+m_1A_y+n_1A_z\\
> A_{y'}=l_2A_x+m_2A_y+n_2A_z\\
> A_{z'}=l_3A_x+m_3A_y+n_3A_z,$$ where
> $$
> l_1^2+m_1^2+n_1^2=1\\
> l_2^2+m_2^2+n_2^2=1\\
> l_3^2+m_3^2+n_3^2=1\\
> l_2l_3+m_2m_3+n_2n_3=0\\
> l_3l_1+m_3m_1+n_3n_1=0\\
> l_1l_2+m_1m_2+n_1n_2=0.
> $$

I don't understand what the author wants to say well.

Let $\vec{r}$ be a position vector.
Suppose $\vec{r}$ is represented by $(x,y,z)$ in an orthogonal coordinate system $S$.
We consider the quantity $(x,y,-z)$.
Suppose $r$ is represented by $(x',y',z')$ in an orthogonal coordinate system $S'$.
We can write
$$
x'=l_1x+m_1y+n_1z\\
y'=l_2x+m_2y+n_2z\\
z'=l_3x+m_3y+n_3z,$$
where
$$
l_1^2+m_1^2+n_1^2=1\\
l_2^2+m_2^2+n_2^2=1\\
l_3^2+m_3^2+n_3^2=1\\
l_2l_3+m_2m_3+n_2n_3=0\\
l_3l_1+m_3m_1+n_3n_1=0\\
l_1l_2+m_1m_2+n_1n_2=0.
$$

But in general the following relations don't hold.
$$
x'=l_1x+m_1y+n_1(-z)\\
y'=l_2x+m_2y+n_2(-z)\\
-z'=l_3x+m_3y+n_3(-z),$$

So, the quantity $(x,y,-z)$ is not a vector.

Am I right?

Comment: Maybe try reading a different book…

Comment: +1 to that. I hesitate to speak too quickly, since it might just be a language barrier, but thinking about vectors this way feels like it would be exhausting.

Comment: The "quantity" $(x,y,-z)$ you came up with is a set of components of a vector in the same coordinate system as that of $(x,y,z)\,.$ The book you are reading cannot be that bad to have made the claim that one is a vector and the other one is not. There can also not be the claim in that book that the "quantity" is only a vector when it is related to $(x,y,z)$ by an orthogonal transformation. Hint: transform a few vectors from Cartesian to Polar coordinates to see what that book means.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old-style approach typically used in physics. I shall explain its purpose.

The mathematical part is very easy. We consider a three-dimensional real vector space $V$ with an inner product $\langle -, - \rangle$. In this abstract setting we do not have coordinates for the elements of $V$. However, we can introduce such coordinates by choosing an orthonormal basis $\mathcal B = (b_1, b_2, b_3)$ for $V$ (this means that $\langle b_i, b_j \rangle = \begin{cases} 1 & i = j \\ 0 & i \ne j \end{cases}$). Then each $v \in V$ has a unique representation
$$v = v_1b_1 + v_2b_2 + v_3b_3$$
with $v_i \in \mathbb R$. These numbers are the *coordinates of $v$ with respect to $\mathcal B$*. The orthonormal basis $\mathcal B$ will also be called a *coordinate system for $V$*.

Choosing coordinate system means nothing else than choosing an orthogonal linear map $\phi : \mathbb R^3 \to V$ (this means that $\langle \phi(a), \phi(b) \rangle = \langle a, b \rangle$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb R^3$; note that the $\phi(e_i)$ form an orthonormal basis of $V$, where the $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb R^3$).

If we choose another orthonormal basis $\mathcal B' =  (b'_1, b'_2, b'_3)$ for $V$, we get another coordinate representation
$$v = v'_1b'_1 + v'_2b'_2 + v'_3b'_3 .$$
What is the relation between the triples $v_{\mathcal B} = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$ and $v_{\mathcal B'} = (v'_1, v'_2, v'_3)$?
Consider the corresponding orthogonal maps $\phi, \phi' : \mathbb R^3 \to V$. Then $(v'_1, v'_2, v'_3) = (\phi' \circ  \phi^{-1})(v_1, v_2, v_3)$. The map $\phi' \circ  \phi^{-1}$ is an orthogonal automorphism of $\mathbb R^3$ which can be represented by an orthonormal matrix
$$ A_{\mathcal B, \mathcal B'}   =\begin{pmatrix}
l_1 & m_1 & n_1 \\
l_2 & m_2 & n_2 \\
l_3 & m_3 & n_3 
\end{pmatrix}$$
Orthonormality means that the six equations in your question are satisfied. We then get
$$\begin{pmatrix}v'_1 \\ v'_2 \\ v'_3\end{pmatrix} = A_{\mathcal B, \mathcal B'} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3\end{pmatrix} .  \tag{1}$$
This gives the three equations in your question. It is the *coordinate transformation rule for vectors $v \in V$*.

We now come to physics which is the more interesting part.

Physical entities like velocity, electric field, etc. live in our $3$-dimensional space, and they are observed and quantified via certain *measurements*. Since space does not have a distinguished coordinate system, we have to *choose* a coordinate system $\mathcal B$ before we make the appropriate measurements to quantify a physical entity $X$. With respect to the chosen coordinate system $\mathcal B$ our measurements produce an $n$-tuple $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ of real numbers describing $X$. For example, quantifying a velocity produces triples. But of course there are entities which need more than three measurement components.

Harashima seems to consider only physical entities $X$ which are quantified by triples. The measurement process associates to each coordinate system $\mathcal B$ a triple $X_{\mathcal B} = (x_1, x_2,x_3)$. But is the resulting collection $\{  X_{\mathcal B} \}$ indexed by all orthonormal bases $\mathcal B$ a vector in the above sense, i.e. does it satisfy the coordinate transformation rule
$$X_{\mathcal B'} = A_{\mathcal B, \mathcal B'} \cdot X_{\mathcal B} ?$$

This is not a priori clear. Some physical entities do and are these are called **vectors** in physics. We could also call them *vectorial entities.*

Other physical entities do not satisfy the coordinate transformation rule, thus they are no vectors in the sense of physics. Well-known examples are *pseudovectors* (aka *axial vectors*) like  angular velocity and angular momentum. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector).

Also have a look at [Conceptual difference between Covariant and Contravariant tensors](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4297246).

Comment: Some key points here, which I think are often missed, are: (1) we must look at how the measurement changes over *all* orthonormal bases. The writing in the OP may give the impression that we just have 2 orthonormal bases.  (2) How the measurement changes depends on the definition of the physical quantity being measured and cannot be determined purely mathematically by thinking of the vector as a list of real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

In his answer Paul Frost gave an explanation what Harashima wanted to say, but I do not think that Harashima formulated it correctly.

He considers a physical quantity and two orthonormal coordinate systems $S$ and $S′$. [Harashima writes orthogonal, but it is clear from the context that he means orthonormal.]   The quantity has coordinate representations $A_S = (A_x,A_y,A_z)$ with respect to $S$ and $A_{S'} = (A'_x,A'_y,A'_z)$ with respect to $S'$. He then says that these triples represent a single vector $\mathbf A$ if **there exists** an orthonormal matrix $M_{S,S'}$ such that $A_{S'} = M_{S,S'} \cdot A_S$. Here $A_S, A_{S'}$ are understood as column vectors.

There are two serious problems here.

1. He does not require that $M_{S,S'}$ is the matrix which represents the coordinate transformation from $S$ to $S'$ (which was denoted by $\phi' \circ \phi^{-1}$ by Paul Frost). But if we allow an arbitrary orthonormal matrix $M_{S,S'}$ such that $A_{S'} = M_{S,S'} \cdot A_S$ (which may be distinct from that representing the coordinate transformation), we may only get a  *coincidental relationship* between $A_S, A_{S'}$.
2. As Ted wrote in a comment, we must consider **all orthonormal bases** and all coordinate representations of the quantity under consideration. If **any two** are related via the matrix of the corresponding coordinate transformation, then they represent a single vector $\mathbf A$. Considering only a single pair $A_S$ and $A_{S'}$ as Harashima is not sufficient. The relation may again be coincidental in that case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a truly wild definition, but I suppose I never understood the way physicists think about things...

An answer your question: no. Also it's worth noting that this passage doesn't define "a vector", it merely defines what it means for two lists of real numbers to *represent the same vector*. So the question cannot be whether $(x,y,-z)$ is a vector, but only whether it represents the same vector as $(x,y,z)$.

In order to determine whether $(x,y,-z)$ is the same vector as $(x,y,z)$, we need to determine whether an appropriate $S'$ exists that transforms $(x,y,z)$ into $(x,y,-z)$.

Indeed, such an $S'$ does exist. Intuitively, it is the "left-handed" coordinate system, if we assume that $S$ is the "right-handed" coordinate system. Formally, we make the following 9 substitutions for the change-of-variables parameters:

$$\begin{bmatrix} l_1&m_1&n_1 \\ l_2&m_2&n_2 \\ l_3&m_3&n_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&-1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Check that these substitutions satisfy the 6 constraints on the parameters (i.e. the 6 equations after "where" in your quote). The notation is a bit awkward, but if you're doing it right the checks will be very easy.

Thus you can see that, using the book's definition, $(x,y,z)$ in the system $S$ and $(x,y,-z)$ in the system $S'$ represent the same vector.

Comment: It is the standard definition, albeit lacks good pedagogy since the book could have given an example how to transform a vector (better to say a vector field) from Cartesian to Polar coordinates and vice versa. Nobody is interested in $(x,y,z)$ versus $(x,y,-z)\,.$ And BTW: physicists think about things not much differently than mathematicians.